# 2+ PORT NIC Explained

Tags: ethernet, nic

I am very confused about two or more port network interface cards (NICs).

Does having 2 port on a NIC allow you to have 2 network interfaces? If I go to ifconfig will it list each port as a separate device with its own IP and MAC?

If it doesn't work like that, please send me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does, It's basically the same as having two one port NICs, only physically more compact.